# Start a service in Activity to monitor Missed calls

Tags: android

I am trying to do the program to monitor Missed calls. I start a service in Activity, and use BroadcastReceiver in service to monitor Missed calls. How to continue monitor Missed calls after Activity is destroyed?
Now I want to a progress of background to realize this. Thanks in advice.

Comment: if you don't stop service explicitly, it will work even if your activity or app is in background.

Comment: Service works in background, even if your activity is no longer active, service is still running on background, till explicitly shutdown in your activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very good tutorial about service in android:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

According to this , your Service will keep working in background until it is stopped explicitly, even if your app is in background or is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Service always keeps running in the background unless you explicitly stop it... Here is a good tutorial that should get you started:

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/37/android-architecture-tutorial-developing-an-app-with-a-background-service-using-ipc/